# Recieving non-sequence email using cfmail

Tags: email, coldfusion, cfmail

This is my first question.

I ran this script,

```
 <cfloop from=1 to=300 index="i">
     Sending email #i# <br>
    <cfmail to="test@email.com" from="test@email.com" subject="Bulk email test - #i#">
    #now()#
    </cfmail>
  </cfloop>
```

- I received 300 email in 90 minutes. Why it is slow ?
- I was getting email not in sequence. For example , 'Bulk email test -7' ,'Bulk email test -232' ,'Bulk email test -86' etc. What is causing it ?
- Is there some kind of setting for it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Many undelivered email from 2010 existed in the spool.Cleared the spool and everything is working fine.